# Simple Modal Popup not displaying after searching JQGrid Results

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Below is my

> [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g27gL/13/)

HTML:

```
<table id="grid"></table>
```

I have an edit button and delete button in my JqGrid.

What my problem is, whenever a search happened in jQGrid, after clearing the values in searchbox, i am not getting any action when i am clicking on edit button and delete button.

Can someone suggest me what is the issue here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) here as buttons are generated dynamically,

```
$('#grid').on('click','.editbtn',function(){
    alert('edit clicked here');
});
$('#grid').on('click','.delbtn',function(){
    alert('delete clicked here');
});
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/g27gL/15/)

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.